# SVN: I have multiple copies of the same working copy. How do I delete one without scheduling the deletion in the repository?

Tags: svn, commit

I'm new to SVN and have a question about deletion.  I have two working copies of the same code.  Copy 1 is located in `~/code/wrkingcpy/` and copy 2 is located in `~/Documents/MATLAB/mfiles/wrkingcpy/`. How can I safely remove copy 1 without scheduling a deletion.

When I run `SVN commit` does it only commit the working copy I'm located in or does it commit all working copies on the local host at once?  Could I just delete the whole code folder which inclodes wrkingcopy (copy 1) and then never commit that copy by never committing while inside that copies folder?

Sorry tongue twister and probably very confusing. I guess my primary question is **when committing does it work recursively and will it delete my repository version or not?**  I want to avoid this. Maybe even another way to reword this is how do I permanently delete a working copy from SVN without having svn commit work.

Thank you for all your help and happy Father's Day 2014 to those hero's out there.

~Dan

Comment: Maybe you'll try to read at least basics from SVN Book?!

Comment: @LazyBadger If you're not familiar with version control, this is an excellent question. The SVN Book never states what happens if you have multiple working copies and what if you delete a working copy without committing changes. Version control is a strange concept for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 2):

Each working copy is a separate working copy and is independent. I many times will have multiple working copies -- each one handling a particular issue. The Subversion does not track working copies. If you do a checkout, and then remove the working copy, Subversion does not care.

If you don't need both working copies, simply delete one (using the OS's delete and not `svn delete`). For example, on Windows, use the `rd /s/q` command to remove the working directory root. On Unix/Linux/Mac, use `rm -rf`.

Changes are only submitted in one working copy at a time. Each one (as I stated before) is completely separate. Therefore, committing a change in one working copy won't affect the other.

Except I was lying just a bit there...

When you commit a change in one working copy, the other working copy will no longer be at the latest revision (duh!). If I want to commit a change in that other working copy, I do have to do a `svn update` to the latest revision which will incorporate the change I committed in my other working copy. This is no different if you and a fellow developer checked out the same project on the same branch. Your fellow developer makes a commit, and you can't commit until you update and get his change.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @David W. I think this is clearing things up more.

So if my unneeded working copy is `~/Wrkingcopy`  and I delete this. Then I type SVN update in `~/`. will it repopulate `~/Wrkingcopy`?

Comment: Nope. Because `~/` isn't even a working copy at all. SVN should fail with an error message if you try doing anything but "checkout" from there.

Comment: No. If you look in the directory `~/Workingcopy`, you will see a subdirectory called `.svn`. This is Subversion's secret. This directory contains the information the working directory needs to know about its connection to the Subversion server. Inside this directory is the Subversion URL, the revision number, what files were modified, etc. You delete this directory, and you no longer have a working directory. In Subversion, the working directory points to the server and not the other way around. The server does no tracking of working directories.